# How to access $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] in constant file laravel

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables

I want to access server name in constant file of laravel, but i am facing   `Undefined index: SERVER_NAME` and when run this condition it gives error

> Constant APIURL already defined

Here is my constant.php

```
 if((isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) && ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'onboarding.posplus.co.za')){

    define('APIURL', 'https://example.com/bib/public/api/v1/'); 
    define('BIBURL','https://example.com/bib/public/assets/');
    define('IS_VERIFY',false);
    define('BUSINESS_URL','https://example.com/api/app/business/validate');
    define('X_API_KEY','234242');
    define('SECRET','dsadad');
    define('IS_HTTPS',FALSE);
    define('DOMAIN','pro');
}else{

    define('APIURL', 'https://example.com/public/bib/public/api/v1/');
    define('BIBURL','https://example.com/public/bib/public/assets/');
    define('IS_VERIFY',true);
    define('BUSINESS_URL','example.com/api/v1/app/business/validate');
    define('X_API_KEY','sdsadss');
    define('SECRET','67889999999');
    define('IS_HTTPS',TRUE);
    define('DOMAIN','qa');
}


define('USERNAME','1n@.com');
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: `$_SERVER` (and other associated variables) only exists during a request.

Comment: @Amadan but how to use in constant because i want to add condition on server name and run url for qa and production server

Comment: @Amadan i want to place same file on Q.A server and production server and run on condition base got it point?

Comment: You could use [`gethostname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first check if the application is running from the console or via an http request:

```
if (!app()->runningInConsole()) {
    // not running in console, must be a request...

    $name = request()->server('SERVER_NAME');

    // your code here ...

} else {
    // console invoked (e.g. artisan)

    $name = gethostname(); // or php_uname('n') for older PHP versions

    // your code here ...
}
```

As to the `APIURL` being defined error, you need to check first if it's defined, then define:

```
if (!defined('APIURL')) {
    define('APIURL', 'http://example.com');
}
```

Comment: when i run command php artisan config:cache it gives error  Constant APIURL already defined

Answer (score 1):

test this code:

```
if(request()->server('SERVER_NAME') == 'onboarding.posplus.co.za')){

    if (!defined('apiurl')) {
        define('apiurl', "https://example.com/bib/public/api/v1/'");
    }

    $biburl = "https://example.com/bib/public/assets/";
    $isVerify = false;
    $businessUrl = "https://www.example.com/api/app/business/validate";
    $x_api_key   =  "234324";
    $secret   =  "sdfsfsdf";
    $isHttp   =  FALSE;
    $domain   =  "pro";

}else{

    if (!defined('apiurl')) {
        define('apiurl', "https://example.com/bib/public/assets/");
    }

    $biburl = "https://example.com/bib/public/assets/";
    $biburl = "https://example.com/public/bib/public/assets/";
    $isVerify = true;
    $businessUrl = "https://example.com/api/v1/app/business/validate";
    $x_api_key   =  "q12313";
    $secret   =  "123123asdasd";
    $isHttp   =  TRUE;
    $domain   =  "qa";

}
```

Comment: i have test this in constant.php file, it's give error  Class request does not exist

Comment: @RaheelAslam which part of laravel you are use this code?

Comment: @RaheelAslam part of laravel such as controller, view? not laravel version

Comment: i am using the constant.php file in laravel

Comment: @RaheelAslam ok, please paste all content of the file into your post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174870/discussion-between-raheel-aslam-and-doldurma).